# how to listen any DOM Event in c# using sdocvw.dll

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, events, dom

I'm trying to connect to Internet Explorer and add listeners to any DOM event, including custom events. How can this be done?
I'm trying this variant, but without any results:

```
//...
using mshtml;
using SHDocVw;
using System.Windows.Browser;
class Test {
    public Test(){
        IWebBrowser2 browser = BrowserHelper.GetBrowserInstance();
        var a = browser.Document as HTMLDocument;

        mydelegate obj = this.somefunction;
        a.attachEvent("onclick", obj);
    }

    public delegate void mydelegate(object sender, HtmlEventArgs args);

    public void somefunction(object sender, HtmlEventArgs args)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
    }
}
```

BrowserHelper returns correct browser instance.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me, without using SHDOCVW directly. I don't know a solution for getting the custom events from the DOM. If you know the list of custom events you want to listen for it can be done easily.

```
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(
                          object sender, 
                          WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // obtain HtmlDocument
            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = webBrowser1.Document;

            // loop over ALL elements in HtmlDoc
            foreach(HtmlElement element in htmlDoc.All)
            {
                // for the HtmlElements type fetch its suported Events
                // from the typeinfo
                // we use a LinqQuery to filter in the future
                var listOfEvents = from domInt in element.GetType().GetEvents()
                                   // where domInt.Name.Contains("click")
                                   select domInt;
                // iterated over the EventMembers
                foreach (var htmlevent in listOfEvents) 
                {
                    // invoke .Net managed AddEventHandler 
                    htmlevent.AddEventHandler(
                        element, 
                        new HtmlElementEventHandler(GenericDomEvent));
                }
            }
        }

        // do usefull stuff with the even raised
        private void GenericDomEvent(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.EventType);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately, I can't vote up yet - I'm newbie here. )
But can I use webBrowser to handle existing Internet Explorer's DOM events (yes, I have custom events list) or I must open the document in a WebBrowser control in the form and force user to work in it?